# c++: Find the closest point on a mesh to a query point

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is what I need:
Given a point(x,y,z) in 3d space, and a mesh compose of some vertices(x,y,z), to calculate and return the close point coordinate on that mesh.
The function probably like this:

```
bool closePointOnMesh(const Point& queryPoint, const Mesh& myMesh, float maxDistance);
```

I have done some searching, and probably I will choose octree to reduce the calculation.

But there are still many details that I can't understand:

1: How the octree node been subdivided, so each node contains may contains 0~some triangles? It is easier to subdivided the cell further based on vertices and just store vertices directly.

2: How the octree structure helps to reduce the calculation, I know if the cell is empty I will just disregard it. But do I need to get all the closest point within each triangle face in a octree cell to the queryPoint, so I finally get the most closest point of all?  that sound still heavy. Beside it will be more easier if I just iter through all the triangles, get the closest point from them, which means no need for the octree???

3: Is there a fast way to get the closest point to a point within a triangle face?

4: how the maxDistance limit helps to reduce the calculation?

Comment: I think it would be easier with a binary BVH especially with spherical bounding volumes. While traversing always visit the closer sphere first and when you have calculated your first distance all spheres behind this distance can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)
Still wondering how octree helps in this kind of situation, I mean for the closest point searching.

Comment: @user1887450 If you want to find the closet point using octree or BVH, you should go down the tree to find the leaf node which your point resides in. Then find the closet point to faces in the leaf node and neighbor leaf nodes, and choose the closest one. There may be some situations which that leaf node and its neighbors are empty, then you have to check the neighbors of neighbors which is not interesting.

Comment: So I still divide the octree based on the mesh vertices, when I search the closest point on triangle face, how can I do that because it is just vertices?  What algorithm do you think is most efficiant for this kind of situation? please, any tips or links or even sources example will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

For #3, here's some code on how to get the [closest point of a triangle](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/552906-closest-point-on-triangle/).  It projects the point onto the triangle's plane, and then clamps the barycentric coordinates to [0,1], and uses those values computes the closest point.

Copied below:

```
vector3 closesPointOnTriangle( const vector3 *triangle, const vector3 &sourcePosition )
{
vector3 edge0 = triangle[1] - triangle[0];
vector3 edge1 = triangle[2] - triangle[0];
vector3 v0 = triangle[0] - sourcePosition;

float a = edge0.dot( edge0 );
float b = edge0.dot( edge1 );
float c = edge1.dot( edge1 );
float d = edge0.dot( v0 );
float e = edge1.dot( v0 );

float det = a*c - b*b;
float s = b*e - c*d;
float t = b*d - a*e;

if ( s + t < det )
{
    if ( s < 0.f )
    {
        if ( t < 0.f )
        {
            if ( d < 0.f )
            {
                s = clamp( -d/a, 0.f, 1.f );
                t = 0.f;
            }
            else
            {
                s = 0.f;
                t = clamp( -e/c, 0.f, 1.f );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            s = 0.f;
            t = clamp( -e/c, 0.f, 1.f );
        }
    }
    else if ( t < 0.f )
    {
        s = clamp( -d/a, 0.f, 1.f );
        t = 0.f;
    }
    else
    {
        float invDet = 1.f / det;
        s *= invDet;
        t *= invDet;
    }
}
else
{
    if ( s < 0.f )
    {
        float tmp0 = b+d;
        float tmp1 = c+e;
        if ( tmp1 > tmp0 )
        {
            float numer = tmp1 - tmp0;
            float denom = a-2*b+c;
            s = clamp( numer/denom, 0.f, 1.f );
            t = 1-s;
        }
        else
        {
            t = clamp( -e/c, 0.f, 1.f );
            s = 0.f;
        }
    }
    else if ( t < 0.f )
    {
        if ( a+d > b+e )
        {
            float numer = c+e-b-d;
            float denom = a-2*b+c;
            s = clamp( numer/denom, 0.f, 1.f );
            t = 1-s;
        }
        else
        {
            s = clamp( -e/c, 0.f, 1.f );
            t = 0.f;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        float numer = c+e-b-d;
        float denom = a-2*b+c;
        s = clamp( numer/denom, 0.f, 1.f );
        t = 1.f - s;
    }
}

return triangle[0] + s * edge0 + t * edge1;
}
```

Comment: my question is if is this really better than just computing the length of 3 vectors and using compare?

Comment: Also to avoid the `sqrt` performance drop (which is not that much), we can compare length2 instead of length.

Comment: Depends if the OP wants the closest vertex (in which case just checking each point makes sense), or the closest point on a mesh (which is what they stated int he question)...

Comment: Yes! You are right! I was thinking he is looking for closest point to one of points on the mesh.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes I wanna the point on the mesh, not necessary the vertices. 
But please, can someone helps to comment out the code above, I will dig in the pdf document and the code, but still don't know how this works...Thanks so much.